# How to draw the tangent bundle of a circle?

Tags: tikz-pgf

To draw some of the tangents lines to a circle I used a single vertical segment tangent to the circle in (1,0) and then rotate with a cycle as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \t in {0,...,30}
{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\s}{360/30*\t}
\draw[rotate=\s](1,-2)--(1,2);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How should I draw the [second figure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_bundle#/media/File:Tangent_bundle.svg)? It is late and I can't figure it out.

Comment: It is late and I'm certainly not going to start from scratch or bother following links elsewhere. Please provide a proper minimal example rather than a code fragment which shows what you've tried. If it is late, get some sleep and post in the morning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to modify your previous example. It's just a little more trigonometry: each tangent space goes a few cm above and below a point (cos *x*, sin *x*), so you use a few more `\pgfmathsetmacro` calls.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[very thick, blue] (0,0) circle [y radius=0.67cm, x radius=1cm];
\foreach \t in {0,...,30}
{
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\s}{360/30*\t}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{cos(\s+10)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{0.67*sin(\s+10)-3}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\yy}{\y+6}
  \draw[thick, red] (\x, \y) -- (\x,\yy);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Only small modification of the Arun Debray answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[ultra thick, blue] (0,0) circle [y radius=0.67cm, x radius=1cm];
\foreach \t in {0,...,30}
{
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\s}{360/30*\t}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{cos(\s+10)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{0.67*sin(\s+10)-2}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\yy}{\y+4}
  \ifnum\t<15
  \scoped[on background layer]
  \draw[thick,red!50] (\x, \y) -- (\x,\yy)
  \else
  \draw[thick,red] (\x, \y) -- (\x,\yy)
  \fi;
}
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I modified your answers a bit and thought somebody might find it useful.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    %\draw (-2,-2.5) grid (3,3);
    \draw[ultra thick, blue] (0,0) circle [y radius=0.5cm, x radius=1cm];
\foreach \t in {0,...,30}
{
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\s}{360/30*\t}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{cos(\s+10)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{0.5*sin(\s+10)-2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\yy}{\y+4}
    \ifnum\t<15
        \scoped[on background layer]
        \draw[thick,red!50] (\x, \y) -- (\x,\yy);
    \else
        \ifnum\t=20
            \draw[thick, black] (\x, \y) -- (\x,\yy);
        \else
            \draw[thick,red] (\x, \y) -- (\x,\yy);
        \fi;
    \fi;
}
    \node[blue] at (1.3,0) {$\mathcal{M}$};
    \node[red] at (1.8,1.5) {$\mathcal{E} = T\mathcal{M}$};


    \pgfmathsetmacro{\s}{360/30*20}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{cos(\s+10)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{0.5*sin(\s+10)-2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\yy}{\y+4}
    \draw (\x, \yy/2+\y/2) node[circle, fill, inner sep=1pt, label=below:$p$] (p) {};
    \node at (\x, \yy+0.2) {$T_p\mathcal{M}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: picture]